# Table for json response

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json response below which i display using li and i save the data as part of doc by data(doc1) but when i go for table instead of list i cant able to save element details data(doc1).help needed pls

```js
JSON RESPONSE
{
   "Envelope":{
      "Body":{
         "processResponse":{
            "NameList":[
               {
                  "EmpId":"1036",
                  "Name":"A Gopalan",
                  "PersonId":"29983"
               },
               {
                  "EmpId":"1904",
                  "Name":"Raghavan, Mr. Gopal",
                  "PersonId":"28795"
               }
            ],
            "client":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessContact",
            "xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessContact"
         }
      },
```

```js
if(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.NameList.length>0)
   displayfeed1(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.NameList);
function displayfeed1(result)
 {
  var ul="";
  var li="";
  
  jQuery('#show1').remove();
          ul = $('#mydemo1');
          ul.html(null);
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) 
            {
             
             var doc1 = result[i];
             
           li = $('<li/>').html(doc1.Name).data(doc1);
           li.append($('<br/>'));
             
              li.append($('<hr>'));
              ul.append(li);
        
            }
 }
```

```html
<ul id="mydemo1" style="text-align:left;"> </ul>
```