# cant able to apply css for table created using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

below is the **javascript table genertion for json response**.here my problem is  css for table row and data is not working but css for table header works.**note:the css given below works well for other normal tables**

```js
var table = $('#mydemo1');
          
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) 
            {
            
             var doc1 = result[i];
            
           var tr = $("<tr><td>").html(doc1.Name).data(doc1);
           tr.append($("</td></tr>"));
             
              
              table.append(tr);

            

            }
```

```css
.mytdemo1 td
{
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px 7px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-break:normal;
  border-color:red;
  color:#444;
  background-color:#F7FDFA;
}
.mytdemo1 th
{
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  padding:10px 7px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-break:normal;
  border-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#26ADE4;
}
.mytdemo1 .mytdemo1-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<table class="mytdemo1" id="mydemo1" style="display:none;border-collapse: collapse; border-color:red;" border="1" > 
 <tr><th>Employee Name</th></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I guess your problem lies here `$("<tr><td>")`, You can not create nodes this way. The string should contain a valid HTML markup. If you check your page source, you will see that the HTML will not be generated the way you want it to be and therefore your CSS properties are not applied properly. See **[THIS](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)**

Comment: I've tested your code with above said modification in JSBin and CSS is getting applied. https://jsbin.com/nojebuyixu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: can u post it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your problem lies here `$("<tr><td>")`.
You can not create nodes this way. The string should contain a valid HTML markup. See jQuery's documentation regarding this [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

If you check your page source, you will see that the HTML will not be generated the way you want it to be and therefore your CSS properties are not applied properly.

I've modified your code a little bit and it is working. Note: This can be achieved in various others ways, one of which is following:

**[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nojebuyixu/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
 var doc1 = result[i];
 var td = $("<td>").html(doc1.Name).data(doc1);
 var tr = $("<tr>").html(td);
```

Instead of `$("<tr><td>")` I created individual nodes i.e. first `<td>` appended the html in it, then appended this `<td>` to the newly created `tr`.

Comment: abhishek !!i cant get what u modified there same code can u bold it here

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used jQuery `append()` function is wrong. `append()` function adds html inside a selector (at the ending position), but it seems that you have used it to create the td/tr closing tags `tr.append($("</td></tr>"));`.

I think you need to check `text()` function.
[jQuery Text Function Link](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your JS is incorrect. You need to append the `<tr><td>` to the table as well. I have modified the JS like this for your better understanding:

```js
var table = $('#mydemo1');          
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
{ 
  var doc1 = 'Content';
  table.append("<tr><td>" + doc1 + "</td></tr>");            
}
```

```css
.mytdemo1 td
{
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px 7px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-break:normal;
  border-color:red;
  color:#444;
  background-color:#F7FDFA;
}
.mytdemo1 th
{
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  padding:10px 7px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-break:normal;
  border-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#26ADE4;
}
.mytdemo1 .mytdemo1-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytdemo1" id="mydemo1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-color:red;" border="1" > 
 <tr><th>Employee Name</th></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: i need to store information as part of **data(doc1)** see above question how to add that to this implementation

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of the data that will be coming as a response. What will be `doc1` more precisely.

Comment: Alorika pls check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309482/table-for-json-response